# PHP: what will be the output of the following and why ? $x=025 echo $x/5;

Tags: php

what will be the output of the following and why ?
$x=025 echo $x/5;
The question deals with php and brings the different between 025 and 25 when divided by 5.

Comment: Why don't you try it out yourself? That code will produce a "_Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token "echo" ..._"

Comment: When you prefix a number with a zero, like `$x = 025;`, PHP will read it as an octal number. Octal `25` is equal decimal `21` so the code above is equal to: `$x = 21; echo $x / 5;` which will be `4.2`

Comment: the output is 4.2

Answer (score 1):

The octal numeral system, or oct for short, is the base-8 number system, and uses the digits 0 to 7, that is to say 10 represents 8 in decimal and 100 represents 64 in decimal.

`25 = Whole`

`025 = Octal`

`025 in octal system = 21`

`so 21/5 = 4.2`